# On model theory (basic)

Tags: logic, model-theory

Could someone help with the following exercise. I am new to model theory and would appreciate any type of help.Thanks in advance!

Claim: Let $T$ be a $\forall \exists$- theory, $(A_i)_{ i \in \omega}$ a family of $\tau$-structures such that $A_i \models T$ and $(A_i)_{i \in \omega}$ form a chain. Show that $A= \bigcup_{i \in \omega} A_i$  defines naturally a $\tau$-structure $A$ that is a model of $T$.

Comment: Some assumption is missing, surely. Do the $A_i$ form a chain, for instance?

Comment: @Andres I don’t think they need to. It is a $\forall\exists$ theory.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Say the theory is $0\ne 1$, $A_0=A_1=\{a,b\}$, but $0^{A_0}=a=1^{A_1}$ and $1^{A_0}=b=0^{A_1}$. What is $\bigcup_{i<2}A_i$?

Comment: @Andres Okay, I see your point. The union must be coherent as a structure.

Comment: @Andres Does it make more sense now ?

Comment: No. You need to deal (explicitly) somehow with examples as the one I gave a few comments above.

Comment: Ohh ok! Now I understood your conversation with @spaceisdarkgreen ! Yes so I guess that $A_i$ forms a chain!

Comment: What is a "$\forall\exists$ theory"?

Comment: A theory $T$ is a $\forall \exists $ theory if you have $\forall \exists $ axiomatization for $T$, which means that $T$ can be axiomatized with formulas of the form $\forall x \exists y \varphi(x,y)$ where $\varphi(x,y)$ is free of quantifiers.